# I want to return a list of length of lines in a file, but my code isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file-handling

I want to return the length on each line as an element in a list named `lst` but
my code is not working, the output always comes to be an empty list. Please tell
me what's wrong with my code.

```
# this is the file

f = open("abcd.txt", 'w')
f.write("Hello How Ar3 you?")
f.write("\nHope You're doing fine")
f.write("\nI'm doing okay too.")
f.write("\nSizole!")
f.close()
```

This is the code I wrote to return a list of length of lines in the file:

```
f = open("abcd.txt", 'r')
t = f.readlines()
print(t)
lst = []
for line in f.readlines():
    lst.append(len(line))
print(lst)
```

Output: `lst == []`

Comment: @HosseinAsadi: The OP wants "to return the length on each line as an element in a list" not how many lines there are in the file — so your suggestion is bogus.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it simple by reading the line once and do the length count.
below code is used list comprehension.

```
texts = f.readlines()
lst = [len(line) for line in texts]
print(lst)
```

Here's the output of the above code. Hope this helps and most of them had given the correct answers.

```
[19, 23, 20, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are calling `f.readlines()` twice. You just need to call it once:

```py
f = open("abcd.txt", 'r')
t = f.readlines()
print(t)
lst = []
# instead of for line in f.readlines(), we can simply use t
for line in t:
    lst.append(len(line))
print(lst)
```

or if the variable `t` is not necessary:

```py
f = open("abcd.txt", 'r')
lst = []
for line in f.readlines():
    lst.append(len(line))
print(lst)
```

`f.readlines()` will move the file pointer to the end of file. Calling it again will return an empty list, which is not what we want.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the file back in the second code snippet, the:

```
t = f.readlines()
...
```

reads the entire file in to list and assigns it to the variable `t`.

You then try to read all the lines again with the:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    ...
```

Which will not work because they have all been read already.

To fix it, just change the `for` loop to this:

```
for line in t:
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read the lines before the loop (that is the line `t = ...` is unnecessary).

In fact doing so is likely causing the problem - once you read the lines, the file pointer is at the end of the file so there's nothing left to read.